# Detect unresponsive .Net thread pool threads

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, dotnet-counters

I've recently spent a lot of time diagnosing a particularly nasty case of hanging threads in a very large server application (simple file operations on a NFS network share would sometimes quietly and permanently lock up their thread). A very difficult part of that process was detecting that the problem has even occurred, since it might affect more or less any thread/task in any of thousands of places.

Are there any metrics or any other means to detect when a thread pool thread is stuck on the same task for over say 10 minutes? That would be enough to indicate a deadlock or a runaway loop, or at the very least improper use of synchronous operations. I'm not talking about [detecting thread pool starvation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-threadpool-starvation) - a single thread dying every now and then might take weeks or months to manifest as proper thread starvation in server environment.

So far the only ways I know are either having custom hearbeat logic built into each task, or regularly manually inspecting thread stacks with windbg/dotnet-stack, neither of which is particularly sustainable long term.

Comment: Well, dotnet-trace and dotnet-dump would only help you when you collect the data during the deadlock, comparing 2 dumps one has a deadlock and the other one hasn't would lead you to the point. Or inspecting the trace and analyzing the hot paths, There is also a tool named dotnet-monitor which combines many tools into one and exposes an endpoint to serve the metrics. You may want to give it a shot.